# How to add a custom 500 error page in CodeIgniter 4?

Tags: codeigniter-4

In CI4 it allows us to add a custom 404 page to be handled by using

```
$routes->set404Override();
```

in Routes.php.

But there is no way to add other custom pages to handle the error status other than 404. Whenever it hits a general error it always display the stack trace error pages, which is not that friendly on user side.

So is there a way that we can add a custom 500 error page in CI4 to be handled like the 404 error?

Comment: The stack trace is only displayed on `development` mode, which should never be turned on for users. Other than that you'd have to catch the `500` in your code and then show a specific page.

Comment: @SimonWeber Where is the exact location to set the environment mode? I changed the CI_ENVIRONMENT = production in the .env file but it still display the same error.

Comment: [That should work](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/general/environments.html?highlight=environment#env). It should display a "Whoops. Something went wrong"-page.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple, by the way.

Simply, create a **new** View file `app/Views/errors/html/error_500.php`.

Notice how I named the View file `error_500.php`.

`500` in this case would represent the Error code, similar to the already existing [`app/Views/errors/html/error_404.php`](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/develop/app/Views/errors/html/error_404.php) to display `404 Page Not Found` exceptions.

After creating the new file, you may adapt the file contents from the general exceptions View [`app/Views/errors/html/error_exception.php`](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/develop/app/Views/errors/html/error_exception.php).

In its simplest form, your new `error_500.php` file may contain:

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title><?= "Error: 500 - Internal Server Error" ?></title>

    <style>
        div.logo {
            height: 200px;
            width: 155px;
            display: inline-block;
            opacity: 0.08;
            position: absolute;
            top: 2rem;
            left: 50%;
            margin-left: -73px;
        }
        body {
            height: 100%;
            background: #fafafa;
            font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            color: #777;
            font-weight: 300;
        }
        h1 {
            font-weight: lighter;
            letter-spacing: normal;
            font-size: 3rem;
            margin-top: 0;
            margin-bottom: 0;
            color: #222;
        }
        .wrap {
            max-width: 1024px;
            margin: 5rem auto;
            padding: 2rem;
            background: #fff;
            text-align: center;
            border: 1px solid #efefef;
            border-radius: 0.5rem;
            position: relative;
        }
        pre {
            white-space: normal;
            margin-top: 1.5rem;
        }
        code {
            background: #fafafa;
            border: 1px solid #efefef;
            padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
            border-radius: 5px;
            display: block;
        }
        p {
            margin-top: 1.5rem;
        }
        .footer {
            margin-top: 2rem;
            border-top: 1px solid #efefef;
            padding: 1em 2em 0 2em;
            font-size: 85%;
            color: #999;
        }
        a:active,
        a:link,
        a:visited {
            color: #dd4814;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h1>Error: 500 - Internal Server Error</h1>

        <p>
            <?php if (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production') : ?>
                <?= nl2br(esc($message)) ?>
            <?php else : ?>
                <?= lang('Errors.weHitASnag')  ?>
            <?php endif ?>
        </p>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Otherwise, if you need something more complex/detailed, copy from the general exceptions View [`app/Views/errors/html/error_exception.php`](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/develop/app/Views/errors/html/error_exception.php) and make changes where necessary.

##### Excerpt from [`app/Views/errors/html/error_exception.php`](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/develop/app/Views/errors/html/error_exception.php)

```php
<?php
use Config\Services;
use CodeIgniter\CodeIgniter;

$errorId = uniqid('error', true);
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex">

    <title><?= esc($title) ?></title>
    <style>
        <?= preg_replace('#[\r\n\t ]+#', ' ', file_get_contents(__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'debug.css')) ?>
    </style>

    <script>
        <?= file_get_contents(__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'debug.js') ?>
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">

    <!-- Header -->
    <div class="header">
        <div class="container">
            <h1><?= esc($title), esc($exception->getCode() ? ' #' . $exception->getCode() : '') ?></h1>
            <p>
                <?= nl2br(esc($exception->getMessage())) ?>
                <a href="https://www.duckduckgo.com/?q=<?= urlencode($title . ' ' . preg_replace('#\'.*\'|".*"#Us', '', $exception->getMessage())) ?>"
                   rel="noreferrer" target="_blank">search &rarr;</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Source -->
    <div class="container">
        <p><b><?= esc(clean_path($file)) ?></b> at line <b><?= esc($line) ?></b></p>

        <?php if (is_file($file)) : ?>
            <div class="source">
                <?= static::highlightFile($file, $line, 15); ?>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>

    <div class="container">

        <ul class="tabs" id="tabs">
            <li><a href="#backtrace">Backtrace</a></li>
            <li><a href="#server">Server</a></li>
            <li><a href="#request">Request</a></li>
            <li><a href="#response">Response</a></li>
            <li><a href="#files">Files</a></li>
            <li><a href="#memory">Memory</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="tab-content">

            <!-- Backtrace -->
            <div class="content" id="backtrace">

                <ol class="trace">
                <?php foreach ($trace as $index => $row) : ?>

                    <li>
                        <p>
                            <!-- Trace info -->
                            <?php if (isset($row['file']) && is_file($row['file'])) :?>
                                <?php
                                if (isset($row['function']) && in_array($row['function'], ['include', 'include_once', 'require', 'require_once'], true)) {
                                    echo esc($row['function'] . ' ' . clean_path($row['file']));
                                } else {
                                    echo esc(clean_path($row['file']) . ' : ' . $row['line']);
                                }
                                ?>
                            <?php else: ?>
                                {PHP internal code}
                            <?php endif; ?>

                            <!-- Class/Method -->
                            <?php if (isset($row['class'])) : ?>
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;&mdash;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?= esc($row['class'] . $row['type'] . $row['function']) ?>
                                <?php if (! empty($row['args'])) : ?>
                                    <?php $argsId = $errorId . 'args' . $index ?>
                                    ( <a href="#" onclick="return toggle('<?= esc($argsId, 'attr') ?>');">arguments</a> )
                                    <div class="args" id="<?= esc($argsId, 'attr') ?>">
                                        <table cellspacing="0">

                                        <?php
                                        $params = null;
                                        // Reflection by name is not available for closure function
                                        if (substr($row['function'], -1) !== '}') {
                                            $mirror = isset($row['class']) ? new ReflectionMethod($row['class'], $row['function']) : new ReflectionFunction($row['function']);
                                            $params = $mirror->getParameters();
                                        }

                                        foreach ($row['args'] as $key => $value) : ?>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><code><?= esc(isset($params[$key]) ? '$' . $params[$key]->name : "#{$key}") ?></code></td>
                                                <td><pre><?= esc(print_r($value, true)) ?></pre></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        <?php endforeach ?>

                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                <?php else : ?>
                                    ()
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>

                            <?php if (! isset($row['class']) && isset($row['function'])) : ?>
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;&mdash;&nbsp;&nbsp;    <?= esc($row['function']) ?>()
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </p>

                        <!-- Source? -->
                        <?php if (isset($row['file']) && is_file($row['file']) && isset($row['class'])) : ?>
                            <div class="source">
                                <?= static::highlightFile($row['file'], $row['line']) ?>
                            </div>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </li>

                <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ol>

            </div>

            <!-- Server -->
            <div class="content" id="server">
                <?php foreach (['_SERVER', '_SESSION'] as $var) : ?>
                    <?php
                    if (empty($GLOBALS[$var]) || ! is_array($GLOBALS[$var])) {
                        continue;
                    } ?>

                    <h3>$<?= esc($var) ?></h3>

                    <table>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Key</th>
                                <th>Value</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <?php foreach ($GLOBALS[$var] as $key => $value) : ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td><?= esc($key) ?></td>
                                <td>
                                    <?php if (is_string($value)) : ?>
                                        <?= esc($value) ?>
                                    <?php else: ?>
                                        <pre><?= esc(print_r($value, true)) ?></pre>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>

                <?php endforeach ?>

                <!-- Constants -->
                <?php $constants = get_defined_constants(true); ?>
                <?php if (! empty($constants['user'])) : ?>
                    <h3>Constants</h3>

                    <table>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Key</th>
                                <th>Value</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <?php foreach ($constants['user'] as $key => $value) : ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td><?= esc($key) ?></td>
                                <td>
                                    <?php if (is_string($value)) : ?>
                                        <?= esc($value) ?>
                                    <?php else: ?>
                                        <pre><?= esc(print_r($value, true)) ?></pre>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>

            <!-- Request -->
            <div class="content" id="request">
                <?php $request = Services::request(); ?>

                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width: 10em">Path</td>
                            <td><?= esc($request->getUri()) ?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>HTTP Method</td>
                            <td><?= esc(strtoupper($request->getMethod())) ?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>IP Address</td>
                            <td><?= esc($request->getIPAddress()) ?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width: 10em">Is AJAX Request?</td>
                            <td><?= $request->isAJAX() ? 'yes' : 'no' ?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Is CLI Request?</td>
                            <td><?= $request->isCLI() ? 'yes' : 'no' ?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Is Secure Request?</td>
                            <td><?= $request->isSecure() ? 'yes' : 'no' ?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>User Agent</td>
                            <td><?= esc($request->getUserAgent()->getAgentString()) ?></td>
                        </tr>

                    </tbody>
                </table>


                <?php $empty = true; ?>
                <?php foreach (['_GET', '_POST', '_COOKIE'] as $var) : ?>
                    <?php
                    if (empty($GLOBALS[$var]) || ! is_array($GLOBALS[$var])) {
                        continue;
                    } ?>

                    <?php $empty = false; ?>

                    <h3>$<?= esc($var) ?></h3>

                    <table style="width: 100%">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Key</th>
                                <th>Value</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <?php foreach ($GLOBALS[$var] as $key => $value) : ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td><?= esc($key) ?></td>
                                <td>
                                    <?php if (is_string($value)) : ?>
                                        <?= esc($value) ?>
                                    <?php else: ?>
                                        <pre><?= esc(print_r($value, true)) ?></pre>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>

                <?php endforeach ?>

                <?php if ($empty) : ?>

                    <div class="alert">
                        No $_GET, $_POST, or $_COOKIE Information to show.
                    </div>

                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php $headers = $request->headers(); ?>
                <?php if (! empty($headers)) : ?>

                    <h3>Headers</h3>

                    <table>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Header</th>
                                <th>Value</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <?php foreach ($headers as $header) : ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td><?= esc($header->getName(), 'html') ?></td>
                                <td><?= esc($header->getValueLine(), 'html') ?></td>
                            </tr>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>

                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>

            <!-- Response -->
            <?php
                $response = Services::response();
                $response->setStatusCode(http_response_code());
            ?>
            <div class="content" id="response">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 15em">Response Status</td>
                        <td><?= esc($response->getStatusCode() . ' - ' . $response->getReasonPhrase()) ?></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

                <?php $headers = $response->headers(); ?>
                <?php if (! empty($headers)) : ?>
                    <?php natsort($headers) ?>

                    <h3>Headers</h3>

                    <table>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Header</th>
                                <th>Value</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <?php foreach (array_keys($headers) as $name) : ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td><?= esc($name, 'html') ?></td>
                                <td><?= esc($response->getHeaderLine($name), 'html') ?></td>
                            </tr>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>

                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>

            <!-- Files -->
            <div class="content" id="files">
                <?php $files = get_included_files(); ?>

                <ol>
                <?php foreach ($files as $file) :?>
                    <li><?= esc(clean_path($file)) ?></li>
                <?php endforeach ?>
                </ol>
            </div>

            <!-- Memory -->
            <div class="content" id="memory">

                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Memory Usage</td>
                            <td><?= esc(static::describeMemory(memory_get_usage(true))) ?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width: 12em">Peak Memory Usage:</td>
                            <td><?= esc(static::describeMemory(memory_get_peak_usage(true))) ?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Memory Limit:</td>
                            <td><?= esc(ini_get('memory_limit')) ?></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

            </div>

        </div>  <!-- /tab-content -->

    </div> <!-- /container -->

    <div class="footer">
        <div class="container">

            <p>
                Displayed at <?= esc(date('H:i:sa')) ?> &mdash;
                PHP: <?= esc(PHP_VERSION) ?>  &mdash;
                CodeIgniter: <?= esc(CodeIgniter::CI_VERSION) ?>
            </p>

        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

##### Bonus Tip

To simulate a `500 - Internal Server Error`, you may manually throw an Exception in your Controller method to confirm if your application is routing to the correct *"custom 500 error page"*.

```php
  throw new \RuntimeException("This is a test for a custom 500 error page.", 500);
```